# Popup (not an error popup)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I want to make a popup with any coding language, I don't mean an error popup with JavaScript but just a div that comes in front and makes the other things grayer.

I hope you understand what I mean, who can help me?

EDIT: I mean something like http://habnote.nl/?utm_source=loggedout (don't matter the website)

Comment: As far as I know you cannot handle the DOM with PHP.

Comment: look into javascript/jQuery, not PHP.

Comment: I want to make a peanut butter and jelly sandwich without using bread or jelly.

Comment: OK actually, you can do this with CSS/HTML only since the popup is already open on page load (but to dismiss the popup you'll still need javascript).

Comment: HERE WITHOUT JAVASCRIPT: [DEMO](http://codepen.io/peiche/pen/vhqym)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortenetly it is possible only on Javascript.
You can either use the simple command `alert(Hello world!)`. Or get it a bit nicer with [alert jQuery plugins](http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/alert-box).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I meant though :P Thought it had something to do with PHP